# Чем заменить CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Tags: php

Привет.

Вот код:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
$uagent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg = curl_error( $ch );
$header = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

$header['errno'] = $err;
$header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
return $header;
}

// ключевое слово
$keyword = 'casino';
// избавляемся от пробелов, если они есть
$keyword = strtr($keyword, ' ', '+');

$url = 'http://search-key.com/keywords.php?keywords='.$keyword.'';

$result = get_web_page( $url );
$err = 0;
if ( $result['errno'] != 0 )
{ 
$err = 1;
}

if ( $result['http_code'] != 200 )
{ 
$err = 1;
}

$page = $result['content'];

$a_pattern = '#<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#sm';
if (preg_match_all($a_pattern, $page,$a_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) 
{ 
foreach ($a_matches as $a)
echo $a[2].'<br>';
}
else echo 'ni 4ego ne naideno!';
```

Пытаюсь запустить, выдает ошибку:

(**Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in**)

Чем можно заменить функцию

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

**Выложил полный код**

Comment: @allanklinton, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: На данный момент не получил исчерпывающий ответ...(((

Answer (score 1):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec_follow($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function curl_exec_follow($ch, &$maxredirect = null) {

  // we emulate a browser here since some websites detect
  // us as a bot and don't let us do our job
  $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5)".
                " Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent );

  $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);

  if (filter_var(ini_get('open_basedir'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) === false 
      && filter_var(ini_get('safe_mode'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) === false
  ) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  } else {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    if ($mr > 0)
    {
      $original_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
      $newurl = $original_url;

      $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);

      curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
      curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
      curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
      do
      {
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        $header = curl_exec($rch);
        if (curl_errno($rch)) {
          $code = 0;
        } else {
          $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
            preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/i', $header, $matches);
            $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));

            // if no scheme is present then the new url is a
            // relative path and thus needs some extra care
            if(!preg_match("/^https?:/i", $newurl)){
              $newurl = $original_url . $newurl;
            }   
          } else {
            $code = 0;
          }
        }
      } while ($code && --$mr);

      curl_close($rch);

      if (!$mr)
      {
        if ($maxredirect === null)
        trigger_error('Too many redirects.', E_USER_WARNING);
        else
        $maxredirect = 0;

        return false;
      }
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    }
  }
  return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in

 on line 21

Была такая же ошибка, выложил полный код... Может, на моем примере получится изменить?

Comment: @allanklinton, поправил код, проверь.